# Remove JSON list string items based on a list of strings

Tags: python, json

Following is my sample json file:

```
    {
        "test": [{
            "Location": "Singapore",
            "Values": [{
                    "Name": "00",
                    "subvalues": [
                        "5782115e1",
                        "688ddd16e",
                        "3e91dc966",
                        "5add96256",
                        "10352cf0f",
                        "17f233d31",
                        "130c09135",
                        "2f49eb2a6",
                        "2ae1ad9e0",
                        "23fd76115"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "01",
                    "subvalues": [
                        "b43678dfe",
                        "202c7f508",
                        "73afcaf7c"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
```

I'm trying to remove from json file using the following list: ["130c09135",                      "2f49eb2a6", "5782115e1", "b43678dfe"]

end result:

```
 {
    "test": [{
        "Location": "Singapore",
        "Values": [{
                "Name": "00",
                "subvalues": [
                    "688ddd16e",
                    "3e91dc966",
                    "5add96256",
                    "10352cf0f",
                    "17f233d31",
                    "2ae1ad9e0",
                    "23fd76115"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "01",
                "subvalues": [
                    "202c7f508",
                    "73afcaf7c"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
 }
```

I know that using replace in text it would break the structure, new to json, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Load the JSON, work with it as with ordinary python data structures, e.g. dicts/lists. Then dump the result back into JSON file. Show what have you tried and ask specific question about problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generalised approach that does not rely on names of keys or depth. The only assumption is that if the dictionary contains **any** list comprised entirely of strings, it will be reconstructed *excluding* certain values - i.e., the EXCLUSIONS set

```
from json import load as LOAD, dumps as DUMPS

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.json'
EXCLUSIONS = {"130c09135", "2f49eb2a6", "5782115e1", "b43678dfe"}

def process(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for v in d.values():
            process(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if all(isinstance(v, str) for v in d):
            d[:] = [v for v in d if v not in EXCLUSIONS]
        else:
            for v in d:
                process(v)
    return d


with open(FILENAME) as data:
    print(DUMPS(process(LOAD(data)), indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "Location": "Singapore",
      "Values": [
        {
          "Name": "00",
          "Subvalues": [
            "688ddd16e",
            "3e91dc966",
            "5add96256",
            "10352cf0f",
            "17f233d31",
            "2ae1ad9e0",
            "23fd76115"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "01",
          "subvalues": [
            "202c7f508",
            "73afcaf7c"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet:

```
import json

toRemoveList = ["130c09135", "2f49eb2a6", "5782115e1", "b43678dfe"]

with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    jsonData = json.loads(file.read())

for valueIndex in range(0, len(jsonData["test"][0]["Values"])):
    value = jsonData["test"][0]["Values"][valueIndex]

    filtered = [x for x in value["Subvalues"] if x not in toRemoveList]

    jsonData["test"][0]["Values"][valueIndex]["Subvalues"] = filtered

with open('newData.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(jsonData, file, indent=4)
```

Note: You must use 'Subvalues' with same writing in every instance. You can't use 'Subvalues' and 'subvalues' in different instances...

Comment: to grab "filtered" you could also have a filter object like this: `filtered = filter(lambda x:x not in toRemoveList, value["SubValues"])` but to export it to json you would have to convert it to list first.